# Live stream video to html for pc browsers and mobile browsers

Tags: html

Please gusy hlep me im new on html and i need someone to help me. They asked me to do a task which is live stream video using html page. I searhed on the internet and I have been tried all methods that I found but it works only on pc browsers

This is the link for my live stream video and it's mp4 format:

http://168.187.49.14:8080

It works fine on vlc player.
Can somebody help me and write the code for me ?
Please I need it and I ask my question here because I know this website is the best website for beginner developers.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation: [HTML5 Video](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp)

```
   <video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
   </video>
```

Comment: I tried it before but it cannot show my link on the html player I dont know why! If there is another way ?

Comment: Puts your video in the same directory where your HTML file is located. <source src="videoname.mp4" type="video/mp4">

Comment: Thank you i will test it and replay back, No need for plugin for mobile browsers?

Comment: Simply edit width of the video to 100%, that will make the video fit the width of the container

Comment: Please provides screenshot or your code, so I can help you.